# Can multiple android views be stored in the same .xml file without belonging to the same parent?

Tags: java, android, xml, viewgroup

I have an android project that has several small views which I need to instantiate at runtime. I haven't been able to figure out a way to store all of these related views in a single xml file and I now there are going to be many of these xml files. I was just wondering if there is any way to have them all in a single file, but not belonging to some parent ViewGroup.

The layout folder in android kinda sucks since there's no way to make subfolders, everything is just piled into the same place, ugh.

I hope someone can tell me of a better way of organizing these things.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want several views meged onto one screen or merged into one xml file. You can include other xml's into one.

> The articles showed you how to use the  tag in XML layouts,
>   to reuse and share your layout code. This article explains the  tag and how it complements the  tag.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Also, this video might help (about 19 minutes in). Shows you how to extract a current layout and be able to include it in others.

Answer (score 0):

a couple things:

Yes, the layout folder is a pain.  I use strict naming conventions to make it bearable, and in eclipse use the shortcut `ctrl + shift + r` to quickly find the layout I am looking for.  Try naming your layouts after your activity:  `activity1_menu_overlay` and `activity1_main`.  With the above shortcut, just type out `Activity1` and it will only show you the relevant layouts.

And if that doesn't work, you can try wrapping all your views in `LinearLayouts` and using `view.setVisibility(View.Gone);` or `view.setVisibility(View.Visible);` to show/hide the appropriate views.

Here is an example of that second one, because it's tough to explain.

one XML file:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout ... android:visibility="visible">
        <copy/paste of view 1>
    </Linearlayout>
    <Linearlayout ... android:visibility="gone">
        <copy/paste of view 2>
    </Linearlayout>
    <Linearlayout ... android:visibility="gone">
        <copy/paste of view 3>
    </Linearlayout>
    <Linearlayout ... android:visibility="gone">
        <copy/paste of view etc.>
    </Linearlayout>
</Linearlayout>
```

keep in mind this approach will require you to define a reference to each "child" `LinearLayout` view in your activity, so you can call `setVisiblity` appropriately.

This approach works well for animations, and I would only use it for 2 or 3 possible views in one xml file.